# Delete all records in a Kaka log compacted topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to delete all the records in a log compacted topic without bringing down the kafka cluster, and without deleting the topic.  Googled quite a bit, but could not find a way to delete all records from a log compacted topic.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: You could set retention.ms to 1, wait a bit and set it back to the original value.

Comment: That only works for "regular" topics, not log compacted topics.

Comment: Try to push tombstone messages to this topic

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander I want to "blindly" delete all entries in the log compacted topic.  (Similar to how "delete_records" script works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the 'cleanup.policy' dynamically with the kafka-topics command. Change it to 'delete', set 'retention.ms' to 1, wait for the delete to happen for up to 5 minutes. Then swap back to a 'compact' policy. https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html#cleanup.policy